# Is it valid to add .html in CMS page URL Key?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add CMS page link in navigation after specific category. I can add CMS page link in first or last position easily but can not find a proper way to add it after specific category. So i create a category name `CMS Page` with url key `cms-page` and place it after specific category. Then i create a CMS Page with URL Key `cms-page.html` and this works for me as my category url will be `http://www.example.com/cms-page.html`. Is this proper way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add only identifier name it's not neccessary to add .html after identifier name. when you write URL key in frontend that time you can add .html for view page.

Comment: category url bind .html in category urlkey as per admin setting.

Comment: @Satish, can you please explain me brief i'm not getting you what you want to do ?

Answer (score 3):

You can add whatever you like as an identifier to a cms page. Even if you name it cms-page.jpg it will still be rendered as html.

That said, why don't you create a staic block "cms-nav" or whatever and then go to your category's display settings and set

> Display Mode = Static Block Only
>
> CMS Block = cms-nav

Comment: I dont want to create static block as i want to use that in footer link also.

Comment: What stops you to do so? Link the category's url in the footer